# Invalid scope field when I create authenticate on xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Instagram API;

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

My code o

```html
public void Login()
  {
    auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
    clientId: "3b5a1...be2f5",
    scope: "basic+public_content+follower_list+comments+relationships+likes",
    authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"),
    redirectUrl: new Uri ("https://Instagramcallback.com/callback")
   
   );

   auth.Completed+= (sender, e) => {
    //DismissViewController(true,null);

     if(e.IsAuthenticated)
    {

     OAuth2Request request= new OAuth2Request("POST", new Uri("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"),null);
     Account loggedInAccount=e.Account; 
     //save the account data for a later session
     AccountStore.Create(this).Save(loggedInAccount,"Instagram");

     // Take access_token out

    }
    else
    {
     // errors be showing at here
    }
   };
   StartActivity (auth.GetUI (this));
```

-e.IsAuthenticated it will be false.->Invalid scope field

OAuth 2.0 authentication, so we create an OAuth2Authenticator. Authenticators are responsible for managing the user interface and communicating with authentication services.

Authenticators take a variety of parameters; in this case, the application's ID, its authorization scope, and Facebook's various service locations are required.

Answer (score 0):

From instagram doc:

> To request multiple scopes at once, simply separate the scopes by a
>   space. In the url, this equates to an escaped space (“+”).

So you should use SPACES not "+" to separate scope authorizations, as xamarin auth does already encode your scope.

```
...
scope: "basic public_content follower_list comments relationships likes",
...
```

+1 if it helped ty!

Comment: I have integrate instagram just using "basic" scope but still I am getting same exception. For more details check this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/449 Do you know how to fix this?